# how to get data from multiple selection server report

Tags: mysql, sql-server, reporting-services

[image]

[image]

2nd dropdown is multiselect. Working fine when i'm selection only one poll when when selecting more than one poll getting error "incorrect syntax near ',' "

My data set query is

```
SELECT tblPS_Question.Question
    ,tblPS_PollSurveyMaster.PollSurveyID
    ,tblPS_PollSurveyMaster.PollSurveyName
FROM tblPS_Question
INNER JOIN tblPS_PollSurveyMaster ON tblPS_Question.PollSurveyID = tblPS_PollSurveyMaster.PollSurveyID
WHERE (tblPS_PollSurveyMaster.IsActive = 1)
    AND (tblPS_PollSurveyMaster.PollSurveyName = @PollSurveyName)
```

I guess @PollSurveyName is taking only one poll name how to pass multiple name so that based on passed names Questions dropdown will get populated.

Comment: you have to write dynamic SQL and store all server name into @PollSurverName with " , "  separate. and use in operator instead of '='

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that @PollSurveyName is the name of the 1st parameter then just change your last line to

```
AND (tblPS_PollSurveyMaster.PollSurveyName IN(@PollSurveyName))
```